# Laravel controller based api routing

Tags: laravel-routing, laravel-passport, laravel-5.6

My normal web app runs w/o any issue. Then I wanted to experiment with APIs. I enabled Passport since I need api authorization (but at this moment, I rather want to get this thing working and I have no idea whether it is a problem with Passport) and I wanted to get simple json output of specific Product. So far, I was not able to get it working. I'll describe contents of each file and if someone can direct me to find the issue in my code, that would be great.

*Resources\Product.php*

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Product extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}
```

*Providers\AuthServiceProviders.php*

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
    Passport::routes();
}
```

*User.php*

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;
    ...
}
```

*ProductController.php*

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function apiShow(Product $product)
    {
        return new ProductResource($product);
    }
    ...
}
```

*routes/api.php*

```
Route::get('/products/{product}', 'ProductController@apiShow');
```

Now if I go to `http://localhost/public/products/1`, it displays the page as expected. But if I type in `http://localhost/public/api/products/1`, it will always go to home page which is set to localhost/public in HomeController.

If I modify routes/api.php as:

```
Route::get('/products/{id}', function($id) {
    return Product::find($id);
});
```

I get the correct json output in the browser.

Comment: type `Route::get('/api/products/{product}', 'ProductController@apiShow');` instead of `Route::get('/products/{product}', 'ProductController@apiShow');`

Comment: @th3g3ntl3m3n then I get Page Not Found error. I think we don't have to prefix route with api since it is handled by the framework (RouteServiceProvider).